# Как можно улучшить данный код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

```
from random import choice

class SlotMachine(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.items  = ['', '', '', '', '']

        self.top    = []
        self.middle = []
        self.bottom = []

    @staticmethod
    def is_win(slots: list) -> bool:
        if len(set(slots)) == 1:
            return True
        
        return False

    @staticmethod
    def is_big_win(slots: list) -> bool:
        
        if ['', '', ''] == slots:
            return True
        
        return False

    def is_lose(self, slots: list) -> bool:
        
        if self.is_win(slots) or self.is_big_win(slots):
            return False
        
        return True

    def try_luck(self) -> tuple:

        self.top    = [choice(self.items) for i in range(3)]
        self.middle = [choice(self.items) for i in range(3)]
        self.bottom = [choice(self.items) for i in range(3)]
        
        timg = "...." + "".join(self.top)    + "....\n" + \
               "↦  " + "".join(self.middle) + "  ↤" + "\n" + \
               "...." + "".join(self.bottom) + "....\n"

        return (timg,
                self.is_big_win(self.middle), 
                self.is_win(self.middle),
                self.is_lose(self.middle)
               )
```

Comment: Почитайте требования к вопросам по инспекции кода: [инспекций кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info)

Comment: Применить улучшайзер. Вы бы хоть текста написали о чем этот код. Его кто-то другой писал?

Comment: Код мой, если что

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убрать все ненужные пустые строки.

Выкинуть все `if`-ы

```
@staticmethod
def is_win(slots: list) -> bool:
    return len(set(slots)) == 1

@staticmethod
def is_big_win(slots: list) -> bool:
    return ['', '', ''] == slots

def is_lose(self, slots: list) -> bool:
    return not (self.is_win(slots) or self.is_big_win(slots))
```